# XML Digital Signature Verifcation

Tags: c#, xml-signature

I have received an XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
 <Envelope>

   <OrgContent>
   </OrgContent>

   <Signature>
     Y7z1Y+c+u80a9vhUSi`....`
     `......`u80a9vhUSi==
   </Signature>

   <Certificate>
     MIIExjCCA66gAwIBAgIJNv5`.......`
     `.....`66gAwIBAgIJNv5=
   </Certificate>

</Envelope>
```

i passed `<signature>` to signed data,`<certificate>` value to pubkey after converting to byte[] array..to the following func..

```
static bool Verify(byte[] signature, byte[] pubKeyBytes)
{
   RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
   RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
   RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = pubKeyBytes;
   RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
   // Hash the data
   SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
   UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
   // byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
   byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(base64Decode());

   // Verify the signature with the hash
   return RSA.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature);
}
```

`base64Decode()` method returns original content converted into `byte[]`.

I am not getting any error but still... `verify()` method is returning `false` and not verifying the signature..(signature is valid). Can anyone tell what is wrong in this code..???

Comment: `pubKeyBytes` used to sign the certificate and `pubKeyBytes` used to verify it must be same, have you cross checked that ?

Comment: You should share more of your code, It's not clear howz your XML is being signed.

Comment: i havnt signed this XML ...i Hav received already signed XML file @yogi

Comment: Then how r u sure that both `pubKeyBytes` are same ? and if you don't know howz the XML is being signed(encrypted) how can you verify(decrypt) it ??

Comment: encryption is done by sender's private key...for decryption and verification his public key is attached with the certificate...using which original content is decoded and converted into byte[] array,,in base64Decode() function...@yogi

Comment: @maatu did you got solution to above problem ?